# Prefix issue when using config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to learn discord.js from (https://discordjs.guide) and I am struck at this issue.

Index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '${prefix}ping') {
        // send back "Pong." to the channel the message was sent in
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }  
    if (message.content === '!test') {
        // send back "Pong." to the channel the message was sent in
        message.channel.send('Test not found');
    }     
});
client.login(token);
```

Config.json

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "Token"
}
```

The issue is that it is not recognizing the prefix at all

If I type `!ping`, there is no reply and I do get reply if I type `!test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes instead of back-tick, which are needed for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So you're checking against: `${prefix}ping` instead of `!ping`

It should be:

```
if (message.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
    // send back "Pong." to the channel the message was sent in
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
```

```js
const prefix = '!';

console.log('${prefix}ping'); // What you have
console.log(`${prefix}ping`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `backtick` instead of single quote. Backtick can be found under esc key and on left side of `1`

```
if (message.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
  // send back "Pong." to the channel the message was sent in
  message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much